# iOS Spritekit load a large background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I currently am working on a Spritekit game where I need to load a background image.  I have a simple 1920x1200 space background image that I am using. The app is being developed for iPad and iPhone.  Here's the problem:

when I don't have a background, the FPS is around 32, which is okay I guess for an iPad.

[image]

But when I do add a background as a SKSpriteNode, the fps drops to around 9fps, which is extremely laggy.

[image]

I have looked into "tiling" the image, but I have had no success so far because there are no repeating tiles.

Is there a way to have SpriteKit dynamically resize or crop the image?

How should I deal with this problem?

Comment: Are you testing in the simulator or on an actual device? Large textures cause FPS drops in the simulator but run fine on actual devices.

Comment: I am testing on the simulator, so that might be the reason.  But currently I don't have an ipad retina to test it on.  Is there a way to improve how it is working now? or is this the proper way to load a background image?

Comment: There's no other way actually. Ignore Simulator performance, only the device counts.